# Exception was thrown during invocation in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine, watch

How to debug watches Visual Studio debugger is unable to show?

[image]

How to know, which exception occurred and how to fix it?

Expression watched is exactly the same as it was in code line earlier, so I suspect Visual Studio just unable to compute certain expressions in debugger.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version?

Comment: Please show the code block in which the error occurs

Comment: @Dims, Do you view the call stack window? Do you use/enable the Exception settings in your VS?

Comment: @Dims, What about this issue in your side? Please searched the stack trace of that exception, maybe you could find the root of the problem. We met this issue before which was related to the InnerException：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400396/configuration-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation